# twig new lines removed by default

Tags: forms, symfony, templates, twig, newline

I am building a custom form field type in symfony using [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html).

In my template for the custom form type field I have several buttons which have no space between them. This seems to be because new lines are stripped from the twig template, although [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control) clearly states that new lines are not being removed. I can also see new lines being removed looking in the source code of the page. What am I missing?

I have the latest twig version installed:

```
"twig/extensions": "~1.0"
```

My custom form field type class:

```
class UploaderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'uploader_form_type';
    }
}
```

My template for the custom form field type:

```
{% block uploader_form_type_widget %}
    {% verbatim %}
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success fileinput-button">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <input type="file" name="mana[]" accept="image/png" multiple>
        </span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary start">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
            <span>Start upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning cancel">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
            <span>Cancel upload</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            <span>Delete</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <!-- The global file processing state -->
        <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
    {% endverbatim %}
{% endblock %}
```

Please notice that neither verbatim tag helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stripped because the form component uses `{% spaceless %}` when rendering the form. However, this was removed some time ago.

It shouldn't make any difference though, the position is handled by CSS not by some spaces in the HTML code.

Comment: What's your answer in the end? There's no space between the buttons in any way, css or html. They are just written on new lines and rendered with spaces between.Inspect [this buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons), there is no space (&nbsp;), neither css padding/margin, but there is a gap between the buttons. Edit html and put them in the same line, the gap will go away.

Comment: I will accept your answer, although not a solution, it helped me find the problem, I remembered I do [application-wide customizations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations), where I have the old widget templates using `{%spaceless%}`. Thanks!